# In angular Import where and how does the 'import' statement look for library files?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. In an angular application, I find this reference very weird...

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Where does this 'from moment' reside in? How does the application know where 'moment' is?

I'm using visual studio code.

Thanks

Comment: did this solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment is a package in your `/node_modules/` folder. It is an external package for time conversions and calculations that has been installed from the npm registry.

Your code is compiled with the typescript compiler.

The settings for the compiler are located in the `tsconfig.json` in your project.

In there you will find a row:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

Which tells typescript that you are using a node.js environment with all installed packages being located in the `/node_modues`/ folder

With the `"node"` option set, typescript will look both in the current folder as well as in the `node_modules` folder to find the needed modules.

You can find out more about module resolution in typescript here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html